# Plotting a 2D gaussian in MATLAB in one color but varaying levels of transparency

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to plot 2D representation of a Gaussian wave function in `MATLAB`. I want the 2D plot to be in one color (green), which gets transparent away from the center of the Gaussian.

When I use `imagesc` (like in the next code) I get a Gaussian over a black square (as shown in the figure below).

I do not want the black backgrount, and I want the Gaussian to be in one color, but gets transparent away from the center, so that I won't get the black square, only green circle (over a white background) where the circle gets transparent away from its center.

How can I do that ???

```
close all;clc

figure
xlim_min=-4;
xlim_max=4;
ylim_min=-4;
ylim_max=4;

ylim([ylim_min ylim_max])
xlim([xlim_min xlim_max])

x=-1:0.001:1;  
y=-1:0.001:1;  
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);

c1=10;
c1_new=c1*0.3;
x_offset=0;
y_offset=0;

w_function=0.5*0.25*exp(-c1_new*((X+x_offset).^2+...
                                      (Y+y_offset).^2));

imagesc(x,y,w_function);

ylim([ylim_min ylim_max])
xlim([xlim_min xlim_max])
```

[image]

Comment: for the "square" I would set to NaN all the values below a certain threshold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain **transparency**, use the [`AlphaData` and `AlphaDataMapping` properties](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html#inputarg_AlphaData) of the image. In the following, I'm explicitly computing the transparency (`alpha`) as an affine function of the data values, in order to specify minimum and maximum transparency values; and I set `AlphaDataMapping` to `none` so those values are used without any modifications.

So, replace your line

> `imagesc(x,y,w_function);`

by

```
min_alpha = .2; % desired minimum alpha
max_alpha = 1; % desired maximum alpha
alpha = min_alpha + (max_alpha-min_alpha)/max(w_function(:))*w_function; % compute alpha
imagesc(x,y,w_function,'AlphaData',alpha,'AlphaDataMapping','none'); % image with alpha
```

Note how the blue part is more transparent (smaller `alpha`) than the yellow part.

[image]

---

To have the color **blend** smoothly with the outer region, set a mininum `alpha` of `0` and define the function on a larger grid. You can also change the **colormap** if desired. Since the transparency already varies, you probably want constant color in the colormap.

```
close all;clc

figure
xlim_min=-4;
xlim_max=4;
ylim_min=-4;
ylim_max=4;

ylim([ylim_min ylim_max])
xlim([xlim_min xlim_max])

x=-2:0.001:2; % large enough that the function approximately ...
y=-2:0.001:2; % ... reaches 0 within this rectangle
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);

c1=10;
c1_new=c1*0.3;
x_offset=0;
y_offset=0;

w_function=0.5*0.25*exp(-c1_new*((X+x_offset).^2+...
                                      (Y+y_offset).^2));

min_alpha = 0; % desired minimum alpha: set to 0
max_alpha = 1; % desired maximum alpha
alpha = min_alpha + (max_alpha-min_alpha)/max(w_function(:))*w_function; % compute alpha
imagesc(x,y,w_function,'AlphaData',alpha,'AlphaDataMapping','none'); % image with alpha
cm = [0 .7 0]; % define colormap: single color, dark green
colormap(cm) % apply colormap

ylim([ylim_min ylim_max])
xlim([xlim_min xlim_max])
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to  get rid altogether of the square around the Gaussian circle ?  and also, how can I change the color to be only green?